# Changing the color of delimited text

Tags: delimiter-matching, color

I am editing text of the form

```
first line
second line
\note{
first line
second line
}
```

I have to leave intact the text that's delimited by curly brackets
and edit the text that's not delimited.    But I keep making mistakes and
editing the delimited text and leaving intact the text I meant to edit.   A way to fix this would be to some how color everything that's contained in `\note{  }`     Is there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not too complicated. Try this:

```
syn match delimited /\\note{\_.\{-}}/ containedin=ALL
hi delimited guifg=red ctermfg=red
```

Of course, you can change *red* to whatever color you want.

Note that this does what you asked for, but it might also do much more than what you asked for because you didn't provide a lot of detail about what *exactly* you want to highlight. For example, look at how this is highlighted:

[image]

Is this what you want? Will you have to handle nested brackets? What about when `\note` doesn't come at the beginning of the line? What about when the closing `}` isn't by itself?

You can refine this regex to do exactly what you want. For example,

```
/^\\note{\_.\{-}}$/
```

will only match if the line starts with `\note` and then the later line *ends* with `}`.

Comment: And may I also suggest the [vim wiki's excellent syntax file tutorial](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_your_own_syntax_files)?

Comment: Thanks @djmcmayhem for this.    For some reason I couldn't get it to work, putting your two lines into my `.vimrc` file.     Your .png suggests you are using a vim gui;   I'm using vim with an `xterm`.    Would that make a difference?         And @Tumbler4, I'm afraid I found the wiki tutorial a bit intimidating.    I wish they would add really basic MWE's that one could just plug in and try.

Comment: @LeoSimon Yes, I am using a vim gui. The gui part is covered by the `guifg` part of my answer, and the terminal part *should* be covered by the `ctermfg` part. I'm not sure why that isn't working. Let me boot up my vm and test out some things in xterm.

Comment: Hi @DJMcMayhem    I've figured out the problem.  I've now put the commands in `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim`      Now try `\documentclass{beamer}\note{The 2016 Presidential campaign was notable for its hyperbole}

\begin{document}
\note{The 2016 Presidential campaign was notable for its hyperbole}
\end{document}`      Highlighting works before the begin{document} command but not after it.      Thoughts?

Comment: @LeoSimon That's really strange, because that works fine for me. Both lines are highlighted. Would you like to discuss this further [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20803/chat)?